# How can I add days in a date like dd/mm/yyyy in powerapps?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, powerapps, days

I have a date in format dd/mm/yyyy and I have tried to add days to it.
My following code writes the label 18:

```
Text(DateValue(Label17.Text);"[$-pt-BR]dd/mm/yyyy";"pt-BR")
```

and this code add days(qtd_dias_para_contato) on label18:

```
DateAdd(DateValue(Label18.Text);Value(ThisItem.Qtde_dias_para_contato);Days)
```

On my computer the above code works but when I open it on my cellphone the data appears like  mm/dd/yyyy. Why?

Comment: have better wording to fine tune the question

Answer (score 0):

The [DateAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-dateadd-datediff) function returns a Date value in PowerApps, and when it needs to be converted to a text value (such as in a label), it will use the default formatting (for the system in which the app is running). If you want to force it to use a certain format, then you need to use the [Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-text) function:

```
Text(
    DateAdd(
        DateValue(Label18.Text);
        Value(ThisItem.Qtde_dias_para_contato);
        Days);
    "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

If this expression is not working (following your comment), you can try "breaking it down" to make sure that all parts are working correctly. For example, try adding a label with the following Text property:

```
Year(DateValue(Label18.Text)) & " - " &
    Month(DateValue(Label18.Text)) & " - " &
    Day(DateValue(Label18.Text))
```

Is it showing the date that you expect (in this case, year - month - day)?

If this is working correctly, we can move on to the next step (Value(ThisItem.Qtde_dias_para_contato)); if you add a label (inside the gallery, I assume) with this Text property:

```
Value(ThisItem.Qtde_dias_para_contato)
```

Does it show the number that you expect? If so, we can move on to the next level (the DateAdd function) - if you add another label with the formula below for its Text property,

```
Year(DateAdd(DateValue(Label18.Text); Value(ThisItem.Qtde_dias_para_contato); Days)) & " - " &
    Month(DateAdd(DateValue(Label18.Text); Value(ThisItem.Qtde_dias_para_contato); Days)) & " - " &
    Day(DateAdd(DateValue(Label18.Text); Value(ThisItem.Qtde_dias_para_contato); Days))
```

Again, does it show the expected date?

Once we know exactly in which point of your expression the issue is happening, it will be easier to find a fix for it.

Comment: It doesn´t work! It added a value on months and shows mm/dd/yyyy in the end. How can I fix that?